# How does electronjs require() return different objects based on L value / variable name

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, node-modules, es6-modules

I am getting my hands dirty on electronjs currently and I haven't dealt with javascript modules up to this attempt.

In electronjs I can do this in the main.js (the main module):

`const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron');`

How can require('electron') return three different object types/classes just based on the name of their variable name/L value?

Where can I find more information on how this functionality works?

I tried to find this by searching but I guess, I was really bad in articulating my problem :)

Thanks in advance, everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`require` returns whatever is exported and this can be an object.

Instantiating variables as in `const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = /* ... */` is known as ["object destructuring"](https://javascript.info/destructuring-assignment#object-destructuring). An object is provided on the right side of the `=` and is destructured such that variables with those names are created and then assigned the values from the matching keys in that provided object.

For example:

```js
const { a, b } = { a: 'one', b: 'two', c: 'three' };
```

is conceptually the same as:

```js
const a = 'one';
const b = 'two';
```

The module you `require` exports an object, and the object destructuring extracts the requested key values, assigning them to similarly named variables. The object can contain more keys, but the destructuring will only extract the key values that you ask for.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! That’s it! Also thanks for giving the underlying mechanism. So I can go and explore a little more for the history of this functionality.